# cmake cross-compile with protobuf telling me no rule to make a shared library

Tags: c++, cmake

I've been working all day to get this program to cross-compile on Ubuntu for raspberry pi. It compiles fine on Ubuntu. But when I try to cross-compile it I get:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so', needed by 'Serial'.  Stop.
```

Now I don't use sodium in Serial, but I remember that is used in protocol-buffer. For the cross-compile I have a sys root rsync'd to my Linux box and I see libsodium.so is in there. When I run `cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../aarch64-linux-gnu.cmake ..` it seems to find the location. I even tried adding libsodium to the target_link_libraries but that didn't help.

This is my cmake output:

```
workstation:~/workspace/frst/serial/build$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../aarch64-linux-gnu.cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Protobuf: /home/me/RPi/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so;-lpthread (found version "3.12.4")
-- /home/me/RPi/sysroot/usr/local/lib/libCppLinuxSerial.a
-- /home/me/RPi/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so-lpthread
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/me/workspace/frst/serial/build
```

I don't understand what the compiler is telling me here. I'm not even sure why it's complaining since this is just a shared library.

-------edit

```
here is my toolchain file:
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)

if(MINGW OR CYGWIN OR WIN32)
  set(UTIL_SEARCH_CMD where)
elseif(UNIX OR APPLE)
  set(UTIL_SEARCH_CMD which)
endif()

set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX aarch64-linux-gnu-)

execute_process(
  COMMAND ${UTIL_SEARCH_CMD} ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}gcc
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE BINUTILS_PATH
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
  )

get_filename_component(ARM_TOOLCHAIN_DIR ${BINUTILS_PATH} DIRECTORY)

# The following is not needed on debian
# Without that flag CMake is not able to pass test compilation check
#set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "--specs=nosys.specs")

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}gcc)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}g++)

set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY ${ARM_TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}objcopy CACHE INTERNAL "objcopy tool")
set(CMAKE_SIZE_UTIL ${ARM_TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}size CACHE INTERNAL "size tool")

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${BINUTILS_PATH})

set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR "qemu-aarch64 -L /usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/")

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "$ENV{HOME}/RPi/sysroot")

set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_DIR} "")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR} "${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/share/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig")
set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR} ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})

# Search for programs only in the build host directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# Search for libraries and headers only in the target directories
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

----edit 2
A little more information, I found that cmake is adding a bad line to build.make

```
Serial: /home/me/RPi/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so
Serial: /home/me/RPi/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so
Serial: /home/me/RPi/sysroot/usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libzmq.so.5.2.5
**Serial: /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsodium.so**
```

That's the wrong place to look for sodium.  Now I don't know why it does that! But if I delete this line the whole project makes.

Comment: Did you forget to set the sysroot (see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#cross-compiling-for-linux for an example) ? (We probably need to see the toolchain file for this.) Where does the lib recide on the machine doing the compilation?

Comment: I added the toolchain file to the question. Both the protobuf and sodium libraries live here on the local machine (this is the sysroot):   ~/RPi/sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/

Comment: You might be having something "default" coming in from the environment e.g. LDFLAGS